# ¿Como capturar dos datos Y obtener el tiempo perdido?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Base de datos]

Hola chicos tengo una consulta un poco urgente y les presentaré el caso para que me puedan entender intentaré ser lo mas claro posible, tengo una base de datos conectada a un PLC que me suministra la velocidad de 3 maquinas con la hora y la fecha de dicha velocidad, lo que quiero hacer es capturar la hora y fecha de cada maquina cuando la velocidad sea <90 y quiero capturar la hora y fecha cuando la maquina sea >90 en ese lapso de tiempo en otra tabla para finalmente hacer una resta de ambas horas y fechas para saber cuanto tiempo duro la maquina sin actividad, muchas gracias espero y me puedan ayudar

PD: Las columnas que defino con el valor "Velocidad" son las que se pueden ver en la imagen:

Recubridoras_PLC_K10_Vel_linea, Recubridoras_PLC_K11_Vel_linea Y PLC_Vinilos_K12_Vel_Maq

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Le recomiendo [edit] su pregunta agregando cuál es la columna que tiene el valor de "Velocidad" o cómo define esta "Velocidad". Es un poco largo de leer, pero lo invito a leer [cómo crear una buena pregunta en SQL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/4092887). entre mas información pueda proporcionar en la pregunta, mas fácil será ayudarle. Saludos.

Comment: Lamentablemente no has sido todo lo claro que querías. La pregunta no se entiende bien. En estos casos conviene siempre poner un ejemplo de lo que esperas obtener. Y... entiendo que sea urgente, pero debes mostrar lo que has intentando, qué resultados estás obteniendo y qué dificulta encuentras en esa implementación, porque este sitio no existe para hacer el trabajo de otros sino para una ayuda mutua, partiendo siempre de que quien pregunta debe mostrar un mínimo esfuerzo de solución de su problema. Falta eso en este caso.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Muchas gracias por tu respuesta lo siento mucho es mi primera vez por aquí ya hice el cambio sugerido

Comment: @jeiferjimenez, no hay problema. Una vez que se familiarice con Stack Overflow en Español, se dará cuenta que las preguntas y respuestas de calidad le será de ayuda a la comunidad.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave ¿podrias ayudarme con este caso?

Comment: @jeiferjimenez solo hasta que agregues mas información. La verdad sigue si ser clara la pregunta. Ejemplo: tu puedes decir: `SELECT DateTime FROM <tu_tabla> WHERE Recubridoras_PLC_K10_Vel_linea < 90 AND Recubridoras_PLC_K11_Vel_linea < 90 AND Y PLC_Vinilos_K12_Vel_Maq < 90` pero no sabemos si hay otras tablas de las que hay que tomar la información. Lee tu pregunta, explícanos paso a paso.

Comment: No seria mas facil recorrer toda la tabla con un cursor (el cursor ordenado por fecha y si se quiere se puede limitar a un periodo de tiempo especifico) y por cada registro verificar cual es diferente de 90 y desde ese capturar la fecha y seguir iterando hasta encontrar el siguiente 90 con eso podriamos carcular en que lapzo estuvo en un estado diferente a 90.

Comment: @MichaelOspina Esto es lo que requiero, me podrías dar ejemplo del codigo por favor?

Comment: @MichaelOspina Compañero muchísimas gracias por el código me manda un error en las siguientes variables declaradas (Must declare the scalar variable "@fecha") "@fallo"  "@fechaInicial" ¿que podría ser?

Comment: Ese error no me replica, me da un error de casteo pero ya lo corregi. Puse un cursor quemado para probarlo. Ten en cuenta el tema de los minutos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero el siguiente código sea de tu ayuda:

```
    DECLARE @fecha datetime, @maquina varchar(5), /*no se que tipo de dato sea*/ 
@fechaInicial datetime, @fallo varchar(2) = 'OK';

/*--debes crear un cursor por cada maquina de la siguiente forma:
DECLARE disponibilidad_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT DateTimeColumn, Recubridoras_PLC_K10_Vel_linea  
FROM tabla  
--si quieres tomar desde cierta fecha descomenta la siguiente linea:
--where DateTimeColumn >= '2017-07-01 08:00:02'
--o si te dan un rango de fechas descomenta la siguiente linea
--where DateTimeColumn between '2017-07-01 08:00:02' and '2017-08-01 08:00:02'
ORDER BY DateTimeColumn;  */
DECLARE disponibilidad_cursor CURSOR FOR   
select '2018-07-24 13:20:12.237', 81 union
select '2018-07-24 15:20:12.237', 95 union
select '2018-07-24 18:20:12.237', 90

OPEN disponibilidad_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM disponibilidad_cursor   
INTO @fecha, @maquina  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

if (@maquina > 90 or @maquina < 90)
begin
    if(@fallo = 'OK')
    begin
        set @fechaInicial = @fecha;
        set @fallo = 'KO';
    end
end
else
begin
    if(@fallo = 'KO')
    begin
        --en este punto ya tenemos la fecha inicial en la que fallo la maquina y la fecha en la volvio a funcionar
        print('La maquina falla durante: '+ CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEDIFF(year, @fechaInicial, @fecha))+' años, '+CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEDIFF(month, @fechaInicial, @fecha))+' meses, '
        +CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEDIFF(day, @fechaInicial, @fecha))+' dias, '+CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEDIFF(hour, @fechaInicial, @fecha))+' horas, '
        +CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEDIFF(minute, @fechaInicial, @fecha))+' minutos, '+CONVERT(varchar(10),DATEDIFF(second, @fechaInicial, @fecha)) + ' segundos.');
        --ahi ya tienes los datos, tu decides si los metes en una tabla temporal y los insertas o no se
        set @fallo = 'OK';
    end
end

    FETCH NEXT FROM disponibilidad_cursor   
    INTO @fecha, @maquina  
END   
CLOSE disponibilidad_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE disponibilidad_cursor;
```

Lo que debes cambiar es el cursor, yo lo comente para hacer la prueba y funciona. Ahora algo que hay que contemplar es el tema de los minutos, para que lo tengas en cuenta. Por lo que veo el me calculo que hubo 5 horas de no disponibilidad, pero me saco las 5 horas en minutos y en segundos tambien, habra que ver como validar eso.

Comment: Excelente compañero ya adapte el código a la base de datos y funciona perfectamente muchísimas gracias, lo que quisiera saber ahora es como hacer para que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo (el código)  e insertar los datos en una tabla seria genial si me ayudarías en eso

Comment: Te recomiendo crear un job, estos los puedes programar para que ejecuten cada cierto tiempo. Ahora el insert lo haces (insert into tabla values(y aqui metes todo lo que quedo en el print o lo que necesites)). Si te ha servido la respuesta no olvides marcarla como respuesta util en la flechita de mano izquierda

Comment: Eres el mejor amigo muchísimas gracias de verdad!

Comment: Si necesitas ayuda en lo del job me cuentas